# Flask disables stardard output when standard output is redirected

Tags: python, flask

I would like to use standard output from my Flask application to communicate status information to other process connected through pipeline, but it turns out that Flask somehow disables standard output when standard output is redirected.

Here is my sample Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

def prepare():
    # Do some preparation work
    pass

prepare()

print('ready')
```

Now compare two different but very similar ways of starting this app:

```
$ FLASK_APP=my_app.py flask run 2>/dev/null
 * Serving Flask app "my_app.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
ready
```

When standard output is redirected, my status message is muted (but application works as evidenced when accessed through web interface):

```
$ FLASK_APP=my_app.py flask run 2>/dev/null | cat
 * Serving Flask app "my_app.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
```

Does anybody know how to allow standard output messages go through pipeline in Flask app?

I can't use web interface for the purpose because I have a function decorated with `@before_first_request` and querying for status will trigger it, which I don't want.

Version information:

```
$ flask --version
Python 3.6.12
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 1.0.1
```